# How to check android project dependencies from gradle panel?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin

[image]

I wan't to check the dependencies of my project and all modules. I run the script in gradle panel, but didn't find any out put after it finished.
Where can i found the output?

Comment: Could not understand what you are asking. You need to be more elaborate in describing the problem